# Convert /etc/network/interfaces to netplan for floating IP

Tags: networking, 18.04, netplan

I am new to the netplan on Ubuntu 18.04, just discovered it exists today.
I have an interface that I am trying to add to create a floating IP on google cloud. It is based on this example:
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/best-practices-floating-ip-addresses#implementing_option_4

I tested the example, and it works, but now I try to do the same on ubuntu, and I don't know how to convert this:

```
cat << EOF >> /etc/network/interfaces
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
    address 10.190.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.255
EOF
```

to netplan.

The output for `ls /etc/netplan` is '50-cloud-init.yaml'. and the output for `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` is:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens4:
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: 42:01:0a:8e:00:3e
            set-name: ens4
```

my ifconfig:

```
# ifconfig  ens4
ens4: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1460
    inet 10.142.0.62  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0
    inet6 fe80::4001:aff:fe8e:3e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 42:01:0a:8e:00:3e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 9430  bytes 1635180 (1.6 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 13383  bytes 1513428 (1.5 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

What is the equivalent of what he said to put in the file, for netplan?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server? When you say "floating IP", do you mean that you want a dynamic IP address, or a static IP address? Is eth0 or ens4 your ethernet device? Do you have multiple machines where you want failover?

Comment: I am using google cloud platform. The vm was generated with 'ens4' ethernet device. When creating the vm, I choose static ip (10.142.0.62), /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml was autogenerated. What I want to do is to add the floating ip as explained in option#4 in the link that is in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `/etc/network/interfaces` is incorrect. You can't ask for "auth eth0" and then set a static address later.

```
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
    address 10.190.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.255
```

If I understand what you're trying to do, then this netplan .yaml snippet is the minimum that you need...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens4:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses:
        - 10.142.0.62/24 # server #1, 10.142.0.63/24 for server #2
        - 10.190.1.1/24  # floating IP in keepalived.conf
      gateway4: 10.142.0.1
```

Assumptions:

- only one ethernet interface, ens4:
- if you have a multiport ethernet card, my .yaml needs additional code
- Ubuntu Server environment
- not using NetworkManager

Comment: only one ethernet interface, yes. ubuntu server, and not using NetworkManager as much as I know (how do I check?) The /etc/network/interfaces in the example is copy-paste from google official doc example in the OP. I tested it and it worked. What I don't understand in your answer is where did the floating IP disappeared (10.190.1.1). This is an explanation about floating/virtual ip https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E41138/html/section_uxg_lzh_nr.html

Comment: So there suppose to be two addresses from the ens4 nic: one static (10.142.0.62) and one virutal/floating (10.190.1.1) that is used for failover.

Comment: @justadev  No, from my understanding, the "floating/virtual IP" is configured in the keepalived .conf files. My .yaml snippet assigns an IP to the hardware in server #1. If 10.142.0.62 is your floating/virtual IP, that needs to go in keepalive, and server addresses could be... say... 10.142.0.2 and 10.142.0.3... and my .yaml would require a simple edit for those addresses on each server.

Comment: @justadev slight edit in my answer.

Comment: thanks, the code edit looks good, I will try, but in yoru comment you mixed things up (10.190.1.1 is the floating point, not 10.142.0.62).  Question: can 10.142.0.62 be assigned by dhcp rather than to be statically declared in the config file? Reason I am asking is because conf file is saved on disk, so if in the future I will create disk snapshot and restore it can cause networking issue. no?

Comment: @justadev  Yes, 10.190.1.1 is the 2nd address I've configured as the floating IP, as per your info. .62 and .63 are example IP's for server #1 and server #2. And no, you can't use dhcp to assign addresses if you're going to declare static addresses. That was the problem with your interfaces file.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you cannot create eth0:0

Check this out: https://netplan.io/examples

```
Multiple addresses on an interface
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
     addresses:
       - 10.100.1.38/24
       - 10.100.1.39/24
     gateway4: 10.100.1.1

Multiple gateways and multiple ips

network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
     addresses:
       - 9.0.0.9/24
       - 10.0.0.10/24
       - 11.0.0.11/24
     #gateway4:    # unset, since we configure routes below
     routes:
       - to: 0.0.0.0/0
         via: 9.0.0.1
         metric: 100
       - to: 0.0.0.0/0
         via: 10.0.0.1
         metric: 100
       - to: 0.0.0.0/0
         via: 11.0.0.1
         metric: 100
```

Comment: You may want to explain how to configure `netplan` to make use of the second IP address/alias?

Comment: You should add the relevant part to your answer, not in the comment.

Comment: This was correct for netplan versions prior to 0.100.  In version 0.100 they added the **label** property to **addresses** that can create *eth0:0*.  See my answer for example.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to netplan version 0.100, this was not supported.  However, version 0.100 added the **lifetime** and **label** properties to the **addresses** values.

You can check your installed netplan version with the following command: `dpkg -l | grep netplan`

This .yaml is untested, but should be close to what you are after (or at least nudge you in the right direction):

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens4:
      dhcp6: no
      dhcp4: no
      optional: false
      addresses: 
        - 10.142.0.62/24
        - 10.190.1.1/24: 
            lifetime: 0
            label: "eth0:0"
```