# Serving DHCP Under Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, dhcp, netplan, systemd-resolved

### Problem Summary

I have two network interfaces in the machine, and need them to behave in the following way:

- **enp3s0**: Main network interface for the machine.  Receive over DHCP an IP address (will be in 172.16.0.0/24), a gateway, and a DNS resolver for the office network and the world at large.  Default route is to this received gateway.
- **enp2s0**: Local subnet consisting of nothing more than 2 meters away, and nothing that should have access to the main network.  *Serve* DHCP on this network (192.168.0.0/24, domain is `.localnet`), and provide the local machine with DNS resolution of `.localnet` clients.

I had a working solution for all this under 16.04 using `/etc/network/` and *dnsmasq* (no NetworkManager), but I'm just lost in the new era of *netplan* and *systemd-resolved*.  Everything just keeps fighting everything else.

So, what's my right, modern solution to make this work right?  Ideally in such a way that I won't have to change it for 20.04.

### Additional information

For reference, here is the script that did what I needed under 16.04.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Configure the PC to use dual network adapters.
#
# usage: dualnetwork.sh <hinetif> <localnetif>
#
# This configuration is based around the use of the classic ifupdown
# configuration files rather than NetworkManager.  This is substantially
# more stable and easier to work with.  It is probably prudent to also
# uninstall NetworkManager once this is done:
#   sudo apt-get remove network-manager
#
# Must run as root.
#
# Rob Gaddi, 29 Jan 2019

GENERATED="Generated by $0 at $(date)"
HINET=$1
LOCALNET=$2

abort () {
    echo $*
    exit 1
}

[[ ! -z "$LOCALNET" ]] || abort Must provide hinet and localnet interfaces.
ip -br addr | grep $HINET    || abort Interface $HINET not found
ip -br addr | grep $LOCALNET || abort Interface $LOCALNET not found

####################################################################
echo Configuring network interfaces
####################################################################
mkdir -p /etc/network/interfaces.d
echo source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d > /etc/network/interfaces
cat <<-CONF > /etc/network/interfaces.d/hinet
    # $GENERATED
    auto $HINET
    iface $HINET inet dhcp
CONF
cat <<-CONF > /etc/network/interfaces.d/localnet 
    # $GENERATED
    allow-hotplug $LOCALNET
    iface $LOCALNET inet static
        address 192.168.0.20/24

    iface $LOCALNET inet static
        address 192.168.254.20/24
CONF

####################################################################
echo Installing and configuring dnsmasq
####################################################################
apt-get install --reinstall -y dnsmasq
mkdir -p /etc/dnsmasq.d
cat <<-CONF > /etc/dnsmasq.d/dualnetwork.conf
    # $GENERATED
    no-negcache
    dhcp-range=192.168.0.100,192.168.0.150,4h
    interface=$LOCALNET
    domain=localnet
    dhcp-fqdn
    log-dhcp
CONF
systemctl enable --now dnsmasq.service
```

### Edit

This differs from [Convert /etc/network/interfaces to netplan for floating IP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102295) in that the problem is not netplanning the machine IP addresses; that part is pretty easy.  The problem is making the system serve DHCP on one network.  When I tried it the obvious way, *dnsmasq* and *systemd-resolved* kept stepping on one another's toes.  When I tried just disabling *systemd-resolvd* and letting *dnsmasq* do all the work it never got the upstream DNS server when it accepted the main network DHCP.

Comment: how and why are dnsmasq and systemd-resolved "stepping on one another's toes"? systemd-resolved should only bind to 127.0.0.53 and should be allowed to manage /etc/resolv.conf, which dnsmasq should not need to touch.  Where is the toe-stepping happening from dnsmasq?

Comment: @slangasek The problem is that I need dnsmasq to be acting as a DNS resolver to be able to access ``.localnet`` resources by name.  On my working systems (16.04) dnsmasq takes over ``/etc/resolv.conf``` and points it to 127.0.0.1.  Then dnsmasq listens on port 53 to serve DNS.

On my non-working 18.04 system, systemd-resolvd points /etc/resolv.conf at 127.0.0.53 as you said.  And systemd-resolve --status shows the company DNS server on enp3s0's chain.  But when I try to dig local addresses I get "Temporary failure in name resolution"

Answer (score 0):

Per `systemd-resolved.service(8)`, there are two possible ways to configure systemd-resolved to know about your dnsmasq server:

- add it to `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` as a "global" DNS server
- add it to a `*.network` file in one of the directories read by systemd-networkd.

For the latter, it may be sufficient to set a `nameservers` option in your netplan config for `enp2s0`, pointing to the local IP that dnsmasq will run on.